# UICollectionView not showing when running on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, ios7, xcode5

I have a `UIViewController` subclass called `FLProfileViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView`. The view of `FLProfileViewController` is added as a subview to another `UIViewController`'s view. The problem is that the `UICollectionView` doesn't render.... **only if I execute the code from XCode 5 (final release)**. Even when running the same project from XCode 5 DP 6, the `UICollectionView` is rendered.

What is more, another instance of the same class is actually rendered when adding its view to a different `UIViewController` of the project.

Debugging the code, I see that `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` is called and returns 1, `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` is called and returns 47.

But `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` are not being called.

Has anyone find a similar problem? Any ideas about what could be going on?

Comment: Show some info about your customCell and flow layout

Comment: `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is never called so I don't think the custom cell has anything to do with it. By the way the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods aren't called either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the problem.

My `UICollectionView` is shown in the first screen of the app. To avoid showing it empty I have a fake app splash screen that extends the default one. The fake splash is shown with `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and doesn't disappear until I receive the data from the server.

The problem seems to be that with the final released version of the iOS7 SDK, the `UICollectionView` is not rendered if it is not visible to the user. In my case I was rendering the `UICollectionView` while the fake splash screen was still on top.

As I said, my solution worked in iOS6, and the iOS7 version shipped with XCode 5 DP 6.

Anyway, this might help someone else.